# Sorting an array of arrays alphabetically by value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of currency codes and their associated countries that looks like this:

```
$currency_list = array(
  "cad" => array("Canada"),
  "eur" => array("Austria", "Belgium", "Estonia"),
  "aed" => array("United Arab Emirates", "Dubai")
);
```

I am outputting them like this:

```
foreach (array_keys($currency_list) as $key) {
  foreach($currency_list[$key] as $value) {
  echo $key." ".$value;
  }
}
```

Which gives me:

> "cad **Canada**", "eur **Austria**", "eur **Belgium**", "eur **Estonia**", "aed **United Arab Emirates**"

How can I sort my $currency_list array so that when I loop through it I get the results in alphabetical order of the country like this:

> "eur **Austria**", "eur **Belgium**", "cad **Canada**", "eur **Estonia**", "aed **United Arab Emirates**"

Comment: You should check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: better use ksort implementation perhaps (for it naturally sorts by keys) instead of "sort": http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sorted = array();
foreach ($currency_list as $currency => $countries) {
    foreach ($countries as $country) {
        $sorted[$country] = $currency;
    }
}

ksort($sorted);

print_r($sorted);  // do your loop here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$currency_list = array(
  "cad" => array("Canada"),
  "eur" => array("Austria", "Belgium", "Estonia"),
  "aed" => array("United Arab Emirates", "Dubai")
);
foreach ($currency_list as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $value1) {
        $newarray[$value1] = $key;
    }
}

ksort($newarray);
foreach($newarray as $key => $value)
{
echo $value." ".$key;
}

Result:eur Austriaeur Belgiumcad Canadaaed Dubaieur Estoniaaed United Arab Emirates
```